# If $x \in [-1,1]$ and $y\in [0,1]$, given that $|x-y| < z$, what values can we constrain $z$ to?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

> We have $x \in [-1,1]$ and $y\in [0,1]$. Then consider the function

$$  f(x,y;z)=
    \begin{cases}
       \frac{1}{N}(x-y)^2 & \quad\text{if}\quad |x-y|\le z \\
       \frac{z }{N}|x-y| - \frac{z^2}{2}&\quad\text{else} 
     \end{cases}
$$

So, for which values of $z$ does $f = \frac{1}{n}(x-y)^2$ and for which values of $z$ does $f=\frac{z }{N}|x-y| - \frac{z^2}{2}?$

We clearly see $(x-y) \in [-2,1],$ so $0<|x-y|<2$. What happens in this interval?

Comment: Please double check the **exact** wording of the problem that was posed to you, and (if needed) edit your query accordingly.

Comment: FYI - the reason you need to check the exact wording, is that what you've written here doesn't make sense. The definition of $f$ puts no restrictions on $z$. It can even be negative, and the function definition still works (that function will be $k_2$ for all values of $x$). Since you've declared that $f$ is only a function of $x$, the $y, z$ are constants, just like $k_1, k_2$. Each set of values for $y, z, k_1, k_2$ will define a different function $f(x)$. It seems likely that you changed something reproducing the problem here.

Comment: @PaulSinclair OK i have edited it, does it make sense now?

Comment: Sorry, your query is **still** gibberish.  " So in terms of this function, I want to know what is the exact range of $z$?"  As specified : [1] $z$ is one of the **input** variables used to compute the function $f$.  Therefore, since $f$ has three input variables, the **domain** of $f$ would be all pertinent feasible values $(x,y,z)$.  The **range** of $f$ refers to the set of all possible output values based on the possible feasible input values for $(x,y,z).$ [2] As you have reasoned out, it is pointless to even consider negative values for $z$. ...see next comment

Comment: Based on the confusion that you have shown on these elementary points, I (again) encourage you to try harder to **exactly reproduce** the original problem from your book/class.  **Avoid** intellectual shortcuts.  Also, once the query is edited with the *faithful* exact reproduction, please **also** edit your query's title to be consistent with the *newly edited* query.  ...see next comment

Comment: Once the query is edited into *some sensible coherent form*, only then can the query be attacked, by a mathSE reviewer asking where you are having trouble, and perhaps giving you appropriate hints/pointers down the path of the solution.  It may be that some mathSE reviewers are more telepathic than I am, and can therefore give a positive response to your query, as is.  I am not that telepathic; I need to see the problem exactly as the book/class presented it to you.

Comment: It is not from a book or class, I just saw the equation and was curious ... I get that $z \in \mathbb{R}$, but the output will be the same for any negative $z$, likewise what would be the maximum value of $z$ such that it will not change the output any further? Does this make sense? If so I will change the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

That function puts no limitations on $z$. That is, the definition is sensible for every real number $z$. As I mentioned in the comment, $z$ can even be negative, in which case
$f(x,y; z) = \frac \alpha N|x - y| - \frac{\alpha^2}2$ for every $x, y$.

There is no basis in what you have given for restricting $z$ to any interval.

Comment: Thanks! I get that $z \in \mathbb{R}$, but the output will be the same for any negative $z$, likewise for $z>1$, right? So the function only changes when $z\in [0,1]$?

Comment: The maximum value of $|x-y|$ over their domains (FYI - "range" is used to describe output values of functions, "domain" is used to describe input values) is $2$, not $1$. So $f$ will be $\frac \alpha N|x - y| - \frac{\alpha^2}2$ for all $z \in (-\infty, 0)$ and will be $\frac 1n(x-y)^2$ for all $z \in [2,\infty)$. For $z \in [0,2), f$ will be discontinuous on the surface $|y - x| = z$, equalling different functions on each side that do not agree at the boundary.

Comment: Why is $f$ discontinuous at $z\in [0,2)$ ? If $z = 1, x = 0.5, y = 0$ then  we get $|x-y| = 0.5$ and so $f = \frac{1}{n}(x-y)^2$?

Comment: "Discontinuous" does not mean "undefined". And note that I said it was discontinuous *on the surface $|y-x| = z$*. $(0.5, 0, 1)$ is nowhere near that surface (which consists of two half-planes with a common border). I note you changed the post once again, but the new version is still discontinuous unless $n$ and $N$ are related in just the right way. For a fixed $z$, as you approach $|y-x| = z$ from one side of the surface the function approaches $\frac {z^2}n$, on the other size it approaches $z^2\left(\frac 1N - \frac 12\right)$. Continuity would require $\frac 1n = \frac 1N - \frac 12$.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I apologise, but I made a typo, and $N=n$... so from this, how is it possible to ensure continuity on the plane $|y-x|=z$? Would I need to remove the $\frac{z^2}{2}$ term from the bottom?

Comment: Yes. Both of the partial functions are the restrictions of continuous functions, so you just need them to agree on the boundary. Even though the boundary is only included in one of them, the other side approaches what the boundary would be for its side. If that value is different from the actual function value there, that is a discontinuity. So you need the two function parts to have the same value when $|x-y| = z$ for the overall function to be continuous.